# Prototype 1 Challenge in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Plane flying on z-axis]

I'm slightly confused with the transform.Rotate on this challenge.

I have the plane moving on the z axis horizontally using left/right keys. However, in the tut it says use "up" to operate the vertical using: "transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime);"

But up just rotates the plane round the y axis so I used "right" instead:
**transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, rotationSpeed * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime);**

Can someone please explain why "up" will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it seems to be Vector3.Right (1,0,0) because your moving along the z-axis for your horizontal movement (actually, the x-axis would be preferable here, if your movement is kept 2D overall as "horizontal" in 2D is along x-axis usually). Z-axis is usually depth.

Transform.Rotate(Vector3 axis, float angle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self)

always rotates around the axis given as if the axis were the pole around which to rotate and in default uses the local coordinate system of the object. So in your case, Vector3.Right actually points towards you (out of the screen) from the local transform of the plane and rotating around this axis tilts the planes nose so to say.

It's a bit fiddly to explain transform rotations but I hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried rotating the player object "plane" and all the associated environment objects, walls etc in the game. Now the plane is moving from left to right on the x axis instead of z axis using same code - transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * horizontalInput); However - transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime); still rotates the plane round the y axis instead of the z axis.

Comment: Maybe the tut is mixing up the directions there as it would be absolutely correct that Vector2.Up (0,1,0) rotates around the y axis. Or maybe "operating the vertical" really means the y-axis. Could you provide a link to said tutorial?

Comment: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/challenge-1-steer-a-plane-through-obstacles-in-the-sky?uv=2020.3&pathwayId=5f7e17e1edbc2a5ec21a20af&missionId=5f71fe63edbc2a00200e9de0&projectId=5caccdfbedbc2a3cef0efe63

Comment: I looked at the freshly downloaded PlayerController of the challenge package and the tilting line starts with Vector3.right, so you did the correct thing there.You also don't need to shift everything so it moves along the x-axis (sorry for that) as the challenge just moves the plane "forward" (+z). I couldn't find where it says to use Vector3.up. Anyway,  you already were on the right track!

`// tilt the plane up/down based on up/down arrow keys`
`transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);`